# How to change Currency INR to $ In Squareup POS?

Tags: customization, square, currency-formatting

By default my currency display as INR (Indian Rupee) in SquareUp POS. How can I change INR to USD?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, the country of your account will determine the currency symbol and currency formatting of your Square Point of Sale app. I’ll pass your request to our product team for consideration as Square works to develop new features.

As an interim, you can create a Square account in the country of that currency to accept payments for that currency. So to be able to accept payments in $, you will need to create a United States Square account which requires a Social Security Number.